# ERROR: for ansible-container Container command '/usr/local/bin/builder.sh' not found or does not exist

Tags: ansible, ansible-container

I am getting the below error when I run

**$ ansible-container build**

```
ERROR: for ansible-container  Container command '/usr/local/bin/builder.sh' not found or does not exist.
```

ansible/container.yml

```
version: "1"
services:
  web:
    image: busybox:latest

registries: {}
```

ansible/main.yml

```
- hosts:
  tasks:
    - name: Copy something
      copy: src=start_here.sh dest=/etc/start_here.sh
```

Comment: Does this path exists /usr/local/bin/builder.sh?

Comment: This is specific to ansible-container tool.  I guess builder.sh will be auto generated when "ansible-container build" is called.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the settings for your conductor.

```
version: "2"
settings:
  conductor:
    base: "centos:7"
```

Then you can start the services section

```
services:
  mongo:
    from: "centos:7"
```